# Ifta calculation - way points - mileage by state

Tags: web-services, google-places-api

We are developing Trucking Management Software web app
for ifta calculation and reporting purposes, I need to calculate a route with 60-120 way points
no directions, just total mileage and mileage by state.
I tried researching but im not sure i can find it,
Can google handle so many way points without directions, can I get a mileage breakdown by state...

Please help

Answer (score 0):

The [Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro) fits your need best. Each request can take up to 25 destinations so you'd have to split up the route into batches of 25 or fewer. Note that the [pricing](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/usage-and-billing) is different if you want simple distances and traffic-independent travel times vs. if you want travel times that take into account traffic information. The API does not split up a leg that crosses state lines, so you'd need to insert waypoints for state borders if you want to divide your mileage tallies by state.

You *could* also use the [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro) (handles up to 25 waypoints between the origin and destination) but its [pricing](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/usage-and-billing) charges the higher price for any request that includes more than 10 waypoints, so it won't be as cost-effective as the Distance Matrix API.